# Why does editing an embed in one part of the code throw an error when it doesn't in another?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently working on a discord bot for Among Us, getting a strange error that I can't seem to fix.

When I try to edit an embed, I haven't been having problems in one part of the code, but when I copy and paste the code to do the exact same thing in another area, it gives me this error:
`discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body`

Here's the code in question:

```py
if emoji == '✅':
            #Add User to lobby members list
            if user in LOBBY_MEMBERS:
                consoleMessage = str(user) + ' is already in the lobby.'
            else:
                LOBBY_MEMBERS.append(user)
                consoleMessage = str(user) + ' has joined the lobby.'
                
                updated_embed=discord.Embed(title="Among Us Lobby", description="Welcome to the among us bot!", color=0x00ff1e)
################Error does not show up here:##########################
                await reaction.message.edit(embed=updated_embed)
if emoji == '❌':
            if user in LOBBY_MEMBERS:
                LOBBY_MEMBERS.remove(user)
                consoleMessage = str(user) + ' has left the lobby.'
                
                updated_embed=discord.Embed(title="Among Us Lobby", description="Welcome to the among us bot!", color=0x00ff1e)
################Error shows up here:##########################
                await reaction.message.edit(embed=updated_embed)
            else:
                consoleMessage = str(user) + ' is not in the lobby. Cannot remove someone who has not joined.'
```

I'm really new to python and I have no clue why it works in one part of the code but not another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

so, it never gets to the upper part if the if/else logic puts it in the opposite block.

if user in LOBBY_MEMBERS is returning TRUE, so you skip calling discord.Embed in the upper block entirely, but it errors when you try calling it in the lower block.

Comment: The other parts of the code work inside the block though, there's code in there that works as expected, so I think it's going through the logic as it's supposed to...

Like other parts of the code are working inside those if/else statements.

Comment: You're never reaching inside the first else because the corresponding if is true.
The second if/else pair returns if is true as well since it's getting you to the discord.Embed call.

Basically, you have a problem with the discord.Embed call which you already know, but there's apparently a logic flow problem as well if you're getting into parts of if/else blocks that you aren't supposed to be in.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the logic since the code works as expected otherwise though... It's literally *just* that one line that's giving me problems and I dunno why.

Comment: So, if you call updated_embed=discord.Embed(title="Among Us Lobby", description="Welcome to the among us bot!", color=0x00ff1e)

outside of any logic loops, it's not giving you issues? ------ Also, what package are you using?

Comment: I uh... figured it out 

There was a chunk of code that I edited out because I thought it wasn't important to the question, turns out it was what was causing the error. Was trying to send a string with no actual value, which was causing the error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I am just an idiot, please ignore me.

There was a chunk of code that I cut out of the question because I thought it wasn't important, turns out it was actually where the issue was

Basically I was creating a list of people who'd joined a lobby, and didn't have a case setup for when there were 0 people in the lobby, hence why when I was testing it, as the only member, then I was getting an error for having no value there.

Thanks for the help!